# ImportError: cannot import name 'warmup_linear'

Tags: pytorch, torch, bert-language-model

While trying to import `warmup_linear`, I'm getting this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'warmup_linear'
```

Import -

```
from pytorch_pretrained_bert.optimization import BertAdam, warmup_linear
```

Requirements file

```
boto3==1.9.198
botocore==1.12.198
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
docutils==0.14
h5py==2.9.0
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.9.4
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
numpy==1.17.0
Pillow==6.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytorch-pretrained-bert==0.6.2
PyYAML==5.1.1
regex==2019.6.8
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
scipy==1.3.0
seqeval==0.0.12
six==1.12.0
torch==1.1.0
torchvision==0.3.0
tqdm==4.32.2
urllib3==1.25.3
```

What needs to be done to import 'warmup_linear'?

Comment: How is `pytorch_pretrained_bert` installed?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa `pip install pytorch_pretrained_bert`

Comment: change the import line to `from pytorch_pretrained_bert.optimization import BertAdam, WarmupLinearSchedule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version 0.4.0 doesn't give this issue.
`pip install pytorch_pretrained_bert==0.4.0`
or downgrading to 0.6.1 solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Change the import line to:

`from pytorch_pretrained_bert.optimization import BertAdam, WarmupLinearSchedule`

as there is no class named `warmup_linear` within `optimization.py` script.